# Get Word After String

Tags: .net, sql, regex, vb.net, string

I want to get the word following the "FROM " part in a DB query. With the following code sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. It seems to depend on the table name length.

```
Private Function GetTableName(Q As String) As String
    'SELECT * FROM _table WHERE column LIKE '%test%'  

    Dim FROMPos As Integer = Q.ToLower.IndexOf("FROM".ToLower)

    If FROMPos > -1 Then
        Dim FirstSpacePos As Integer = Q.ToLower.IndexOf(Chr(32), FROMPos)

        If FirstSpacePos > -1 Then
            Dim EndSpacePos As Integer = Q.ToLower.IndexOf(Chr(32), FirstSpacePos + 1)

            If EndSpacePos > -1 Then
                'MsgBox(Q.Substring(FirstSpacePos + 1, EndSpacePos - FirstSpacePos))
                Return Q.Substring(FirstSpacePos + 1, EndSpacePos - FirstSpacePos)
            Else
                Return ""
            End If
        Else
            Return ""
        End If
    Else
        Return ""
    End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes a good regex is all you need (tested in LinqPad, hence the `.Dump()` call).

```
Dim queries = New List(Of String)() From { _
    "select * from my_table", _
    "select * from [dbo].[table with spaces] tws where tws.id = @id", _
    "select * from [dbo].[table with spaces] tws where tws.id in (select x.id from [some_other_table] x)" _
}

For Each query As String In queries
    Dim matches = Regex.Matches(query, "from\s+((?:(?:\[[^\]]+\])|[^\s])+)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
    For Each m As Match In matches
        m.Groups(1).Value.Dump()
    Next
Next
```

Results:

> ```
> my_table
> [dbo].[table with spaces]
> [dbo].[table with spaces]
> [some_other_table]
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Note, you would probably be better off using a comprehensive query parser but it does answer your question.

**vb.net**

Public Shared Function GetTableName(query As String) As String
    Dim tableName = String.Empty

```
Dim fromPos = query.IndexOf(" FROM", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
If fromPos = -1 Then
    Return tableName
End If

tableName = query.Substring(fromPos + 6)

' check if there is a schema
If tableName.IndexOf("] ", StringComparison.Ordinal) = -1 Then
    ' query does not contain [dbo].[tableName] schema
    tableName = tableName.Substring(0, tableName.IndexOf(" ", StringComparison.Ordinal))
Else
    ' query contains some form of schema
    tableName = tableName.Substring(0, tableName.IndexOf("] ", StringComparison.Ordinal) + 1)
End If

Return tableName
```

End Function

**c#**

```
public static string GetTableName(string query)
{
    var tableName = string.Empty;

    var fromPos = query.IndexOf(" FROM", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    if (fromPos == -1)
    {
        return tableName;
    }

    tableName = query.Substring(fromPos + 6); 

    // check if there is a schema
    if (tableName.IndexOf("] ", StringComparison.Ordinal) == -1)
    {
        // query does not contain [dbo].[tableName] schema
        tableName = tableName.Substring(0, tableName.IndexOf(" ", StringComparison.Ordinal) );
    }
    else
    {
        // query contains some form of schema
        tableName = tableName.Substring(0, tableName.IndexOf("] ", StringComparison.Ordinal) + 1);
    }

    return tableName;
}
```

**Tests**

```
GetTableName("fkgsejrtlekrjgsdlkfgjsdfg") 
// Returns Empty string

GetTableName("SELECT * FROM _table WHERE column LIKE '%test%")) 
// Returns _table

GetTableName("SELECT * FROM SomeReallyReallyLongTableName WHERE column LIKE '%test%"))
// Returns SomeReallyReallyLongTableName

GetTableName("SELECT * FROM [dbo].[My Table] WHERE column LIKE '%test%"))
// Returns [dbo].[My Table]
```

Comment: "comprehensive query parser" google doesnt really show me what im looking for. could u give me a hint what u mean? thank you!

Comment: He means that if you want to do real language parsing the way a compiler does, you need to look into a CFG (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar).  There's a SQL grammer available here for GOLDParser: http://goldparser.org/grammars/   Another common language parser is ANTLR (http://www.antlr.org/).